# Variable not passed by reference

Tags: php, sql-server

When I insert a row into my ms-sql server database, I have the following error:

> **Warning:** Variable parameter 3 not passed by reference (prefaced with an `&`). Variable parameters passed to `sqlsrv_prepare` or `sqlsrv_query` should be passed by reference, not by value. For more information, see `sqlsrv_prepare` or `sqlsrv_query` in the API Reference section of the product documentation. in `C:\...\ImmoToevoegen.php` on line 6

The same warning for parameter 1 and 2.

This is my php code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['omschrijving']) && !empty($_POST['woningtype']) && !empty($_POST['data'])){
    $oms = $_POST['omschrijving'];
    $type = $_POST['woningtype'];
    $data = json_encode($_POST['data']);

    $prep = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "insert into Woning(omschrijving, data, typeid) values (?, ?,  ?);", array($oms, $data, $type));
    sqlsrv_execute($prep);

    print "Woning is toegevoegd";
}
?>

<form action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <!--param 1 "omschrijving"-->
    Omschrijving:
    <textarea name="omschrijving" id="omschrijving" cols="30" rows="10></textarea>

    <!--param 2 "data"-->
    <div>
        wc: <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="wc"/><br/>
        cv: <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="cv"/><br/>
        boiler: <input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="boiler"/><br/>
    </div>

    <!--param 3 "woningtype"-->
    <select name="woningtype" id="woningtype">
        <?php
        //code for load data from database
        print "<option value='" . $rij["ID"] . "'>" . $rij["naam"] . "</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I use like I said php with a ms-sql server database.

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: are you not using form tags with a POST method?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i do. i go update my question

Comment: "What is wrong with my code? "  ..apart from the missing `form` tag..  missing `form method`..  missing `form submission` action..

Comment: @ChrisMaggs: i have update my question and added the `form` tag. i was forget to place it in my question

Comment: snice you're using this all inside one file, use `isset()` or `!empty()` on the POST arrays, see if that helps.

Comment: Try adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything besides the sql errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign your values to a variable, then pass that variable to the PDO/sqlsrv

```
<?php
$var = json_encode($_POST['data']);
//checks for all fields are filled in.
$prep = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "insert into Woning(omschrijving, data, typeid) values (?, ?,  ?);",
    array($_POST['omschrijving'], $var, $_POST['woningtype']));
sqlsrv_execute($prep);
?>
```

PDO/sqlsrv is a "native" library. It will not retain any reference of function output because it doesn't have a name to give it. If you pass it a variable the DLL's can query PHP "Hey, whats the value $variable at this point in time?"

A function output is "fleeting" doesn't have a "name" and gets lost in memory.

Always assign your function outputs to variables that survive until you call the `sqlsrv_execute()` and keep in mind not to overwrite them.

**edit**

A little and above duty, but I really advice you to investigate how variables work.

A variable consists of 4 components:

- A reference: The $iAmAVariable
- A reference value: :0xa384dee
- A Value: "I am a String";
- A Memory Address: 0xa384dee

The reference value points to the memory address where the value is stored. This reference value is what's  stored in the reference. Not the value itself.

The reference is merely used to look up what the memory address is where the variable is stored. With that adress it can read that specific region of the RAM and retrieve the value.

When you delete the reference `unset($iAmAVariable)` or set the reference to another variable `$iAmAvariable = ""` you do not wipe the memory address or the value. You are just deleting your access to that value/and or setting it to a new value at a new address

PHP itself still has a reference to that value. Once in a while it'll do a garbage collection run and delete all values that do not have references attached.

What happens with a function output that is not assigned to a variable that is passed to a native library? The PHP garbage collector cannot check any references a native library might have to PHP variables because it runs in totally separate user space.

The moment a variable passes from PHP space to native space, and there is no reference to it in the PHP space, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

This is what is happening in the code sample where you are experiencing a problem. That is why you are getting the error you are getting.

The function variables and return values only live for as long as the function lives. The moment it returns it values everything is voided and eligible for garbage collection.

You are still passing along a function output to the sqlsrv library, which will void itself after it has returned.

```
$prep = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "insert into Woning(omschrijving, data, typeid) values (?, ?,  ?);", array($oms, $data, $type));
```

`array()` is also a function.

I suggest you try

```
$params = array($oms, $data, $type);
$prep = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, "insert into Woning(omschrijving, data, typeid) values (?, ?,  ?);", $params);
```

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: I'm wondering what PDO has anything to do with this code, since it's using the [SQLSrv extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php), and not PDO? You know, on account of using the `sqlsrv_*` functions, which aren't in any way, shape, or form, a part of PDO ;)

Comment: Yea, i added sqlsrv later on but missed the first one. The variable binding is the same regardless if you use pdo or sqlsrv. You need to pass the reference. Not function output.

Comment: I modified my answer @Luïs can you see if this helps you?